# Copy cookie to other domain. Firefox? Chromium?

Tags: firefox, cookies, chromium

Is there any possibility of copying a set of cookies from one domain to another. I badly need this for Web development.

Comment: Please add more detail. What are you trying to do? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If this is a domain migration, have the users sign in to the old site, which can then post the full cookies to a url on the new site. Voila, cookies migrated

Comment: @Pekka: I need the same cookies for localhost and global domain, the cookies can solely be generated by the global domain server.

Comment: @sehe: No, it is for development purposes.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The cookies contain information from Facebook and I can only query this from a global domain. I would like to mirror the cookies to _localhost_, in order to use them locally.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just copy set of cookies, but you can write your own php/python code, to set several cookies for another domain and use values from the old set.

Comment: I tried this, but I think the browser prohibits setting cookies for a different domain... The cookies are not set actually.

Comment: That's correct, you cannot set cookie for other domain, but... You can create virtualhost which would have the appropriate domain name and set your /etc/hosts file, that this domainname points to localhost instead of original source. This time you can set cookies for any domain you like.

Answer (score 0):

No, the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prohibits sites from setting or reading cookies on behalf of other sites outside of a few special cases. Some browser extensions will allow you to copy and paste cookies to sync them manually, though.

Comment: That is the reason I asked. I do not want the _site_ to copy the cookie because I know this isn't possible, but rather the _browser_ (extension/plugin/add-on/...).

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it sounds like you want to use the same cookie for your development and your production system. How about using something like 'local.example.com' instead of 'localhost' as your development domain and setting wildcard cookies for all subdomains?

We use this pattern so we don't need to register multiple API keys for webservices since most of them have wildcard support for subdomains.

I'm not sure I would recommend something like that so you are able to use the same cookies in development and production because it has other implications as well. For example if you send static assets from another subdomain then the browser will send cookie header information unnecessarily and of course there might be some more details that might make debugging harder rather than easier this way.

If you could explain the problem at hand in a bit more detail there might be other solutions or best practices for staging and production environments that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually, using grease monkey.

goto tools->page info.
select security tab.
view cookies button.
type the domain you wish to read from.
make a note of all the cookies and their content.
now go to the domain you wish to copy to.
install greasemonkey add on for firefox (or better yet, using Cookies Manager+ :: Add-ons for Firefox!).
run some javascript code to re-create the mentioned cookeis and their values.